# Using python dash dcc.upload component inside a docker container

Tags: docker

I have a python dash app consisting among other components of a dcc.upload component. Everything works fine when running on my computer. I want the dcc. upload component to only have access to the files inside the container.

I put the application inside a docker container and expected the dcc.upload component to only have access to the files inside the docker container, which I specified in the Dockerfile. But somehow the dcc.upload component still has access to the whole filesystem on my machine. Why is that?

Probably I am getting some behaviour of the docker wrong, as I am still new to it. If anybody sees where my thoughts took a wrong turn, please let me know.

This is an exemplary source code for building a python dash app with an upload component:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, dash_table, Input, Output, State, callback

import base64
import datetime
import io

import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
])

def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

    return html.Div([
        html.H5(filename),
        html.H6(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)),

        dash_table.DataTable(
            df.to_dict('records'),
            [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns]
        ),

        html.Hr(),  # horizontal line

        # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
        html.Div('Raw Content'),
        html.Pre(contents[0:200] + '...', style={
            'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
            'wordBreak': 'break-all'
        })
    ])

@callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
            Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
            State('upload-data', 'filename'),
            State('upload-data', 'last_modified'))
def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]
        return children

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8030, debug=True)
```

This is the Dockerfile I am using:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
Copy app_3.py /code

COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
CMD python app_3.py
```

With this app I can access the whole filesystem on my computer. But I want to restrict the access only to the files inside the Docker Container (or e.g. using a volume).
To dockerize the app I run in a GitBash Terminal on Windows having the Docker Engine from Docker Deskop running:

```
docker build -t ImageName .
docker run -d --name ContainerName -p 8030:8030 ImageName
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi there, please share some source code to reproduce and expected output at least what you are gettin~

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov Sure, hope this helps!